# IIF won't evaluate for both numbers and strings

Tags: reporting-services

Given a sample set of inputs:

```
.5
1
1.333333
Over
N/A
0
```

I have tried to conditionally format the background color using an expression such as

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value < 1 , "Yellow",
 IIF(ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value = "Over" , "Red",
 "Blue"))
```

However, no matter how I try to fix this it will only work for either the strings or the numbers, sometimes neither, but never both. Oddly, I can (by using a conversion function on the `ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value` to make it explicitly a string or a number) get it to work for some of the rows, leaving the others with a white background (where in my `IIF` is "White"?).

Comment: What if you use a switch statement instead?

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin Switch didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=IIF(
   IsNumeric(ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value),
   IIF(ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value < 1,"Yellow",Nothing),
   IIF(ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value = "Over" , "Red","Blue")
 )
```

**UPDATE:** It seems IsNumeric is not evaluated to false when the value is a string causing an error.

Go to `Report` menu / `Report Properties` / and under the `Code` tab paste this custom VB function.

```
Public Function GetColor(ByVal value as String) As String
  Dim color As String
  Dim numberValue As Double
  if IsNumeric(value) Then
     numberValue = Cdbl(Val(value))
     color = iif(numberValue < 1, "Yellow", "Transparent")
  else
     color = iif(value = "Over","Red","Blue")
  End if
  return color
End Function
```

Now in the background color property you can call this custom function passing the value for `Onhand_PCT` value as argument to the function.

```
=Code.GetColor(ReportItems!Onhand_PCT.Value)
```

[image]

> Note the `Onhand_PCT >= 1` will be transparent, you can customize that
>   by changing the `"Transparent"` in the custom function.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Everything came out white.

Comment: @tenmiles, what color should appear if the value is greater or equal to 1? Also Onhand_PCT report item is a cell in the tablix, what is the expression it is set to?

Comment: I think you have to convert `value` to a numeric type in your `IIF` comparison if `IsNumeric` evaluates to true.  0.5 still has a white background in your picture. I like this solution though.

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin,you are right it seems the IIF comparisions implicitely convert the string number to integer taking its decimal as the entire part. i.e 0.5 is converted to 5. To avoid that I've added a couple of lines in the custom function.